# Find sum of $5$th powers from given equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x+y+z=1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$ $$x^2+y^2+z^2=2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$ $$x^3+y^3+z^3=3\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$ $$x^5+y^5+z^5=\ ?$$
I got this question from [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/4FNCIYD8HdA). The guy there, @Presh, explains a bunch of complicated stuff and gets the answer as $6$.

Is there a simpler method for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squaring equation $(1)$ and subtracting $(2)$, we get $$2(xy+yz+zx)=-1$$ $$xy+yz+zx=\frac{-1}{2}$$
Subtracting $3xyz$ from both sides of $(3)$, we get $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)=2+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{2}=3-3xyz$$ $$xyz={1\over 6}$$
Now let us form a cubic equation in variable $v$ with roots $x,y,z$.

Using the theory of equations, we get $$v^3-v^2-{v\over 2}-{1\over 6}=0$$ Or, $$6v^3-6v^2-3v-1=0$$ $$6v^3=6v^2+3v+1$$ $$6v^4=6v^3+3v^2+v$$
Since $x,y,z$ satisfy this equation, $$6x^4=6x^3+3x^2+x$$ $$6y^4=6y^3+3y^2+y$$ $$6z^4=6z^3+3z^2+z$$
Adding these three equations, $$6(x^4+y^4+z^4)=6(3)+3(2)+(1)=25$$ $$x^4+y^4+z^4=\frac{25}{6}$$
Again, $$6x^5=6x^4+3x^3+x^2$$ $$6y^5=6y^4+3y^3+y^2$$ $$6z^5=6z^4+3z^3+z^2$$
Adding all three, $$6(x^5+y^5+z^5)=6\left(\frac{25}{6} \right)+3(3)+(2)=36$$ $$x^5+y^5+z^5=6$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply equation $(2)$ by equation $(3)$:

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^3+y^3+z^3)=x^5+y^5+z^5+(x^2y^3+x^2z^3+y^2x^3+y^2z^3+z^2x^3+z^2y^3)$$

So $\quad x^5+y^5+z^5=6-t\quad$ where $\quad t=x^2y^3+x^2z^3+y^2x^3+y^2z^3+z^2x^3+z^2y^3$.

Now rewrite $t$ as :

$$t=x^2y^2(x+y)+x^2z^2(x+z)+y^2z^2(y+z)$$
From equation $(1)$ we can rewrite it as:
$$t=x^2y^2(1-z)+x^2z^2(1-y)+y^2z^2(1-x)$$
$$=x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2-xyz(xy+xz+yz)$$
We can find $xy+xz+yz$ from equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ :

$$2xy+2yz+2xz=(x+y+z)^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$
$$xy+yz+xz=-\frac12$$
Now square it:
$$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2+2xyz(x+y+z)=\frac14$$
By repeating the process to in your answer, we have $xyz=\frac16$. so
$$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2=\frac14-\frac13=-\frac1{12}$$
Therefore $t=x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2-xyz(xy+xz+yz)=\frac{-1}{12}-(\frac16\times\frac{-1}2)=0$

And $x^5+y^5+z^5=6-t=6$